# Does AWS certificate manager auto deploy to my resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I ask this because there are many resources out there for Lets Encrypt to auto renew and deploy (via Lambda) to ELBs. Doesn't AWS' Certificate Manager do the same thing?

https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/

Says:

> Q: What can I do with AWS Certificate Manager?
>
> ...
>
> ACM manages certificate renewals and certificate deployment for you.

However the AWS docs don't talk about this at all.

So if I understand this correctly...

1. I request a cert
2. Verify the cert in my email
3. Manually deploy the cert
4. ACM will every year renew my cert and deploy my cert back to all the resources I deployed it to previously

Is this correct? Is there documentation that talks about this explicitly?

Any direction on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using AWS SSL Certificates from Certificate Manager, renewal is automatically handled and changing the certificate from your application load balancer or CloudFront is not required.

Check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/managed-renewal.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: I keeps talking about "renewing" but not "deploying" that's my hang up. I need it to be deployed as well as be renewed automatically. I think an important phrase is "the certificate's Amazon Resource Name (ARN) remains the same." which leads me to believe that maybe the whole idea of "deploying" isn't needed with AWS since the cert if referenced via the ARN? Is my thinking there correct?

Comment: When using AWS Issued certificates with AWS services, its a reference configuration we are doing to tell Amazon to use a particular certificate. Amazon links the certificate from ARN so renewal doesn't require redeploy or change the usage configurations.